# Generate two other columns with functions and conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

**Input table:**

```
store    | employee  | date             |  timein  | timeout |   
    1    |      A    |        1-jan-12  |  10:00   | 17:00   |
    1    |      A    |        1-jan-12  |  20:00   | 22:00   |
    2    |      B    |        1-jan-12  |  10:00   |  -      |
    2    |      B    |        1-jan-12  |  17:00   | 20:00   |
    2    |      B    |        2-jan-12  |  10:00   | 17:00   |
    3    |      C    |        1-jan-12  |  10:00   | 12:00   |
    3    |      C    |        1-jan-12  |  13:00   | 15:00   |
    3    |      C    |        1-jan-12  |  20:00   | 23:00   |
```

**Desired ouptput:**

```
store | employee | date      |  timein  | timeout | hours | working_days |
 1    |     A    | 1-jan-12  |  10:00   | 17:00   |   7   |              |
 1    |     A    | 1-jan-12  |  20:00   | 22:00   |   2   |        1     |
 2    |     B    | 1-jan-12  |  10:00   |  -      |   0   |              | 
 2    |     B    | 1-jan-12  |  17:00   | 20:00   |   5   |        0     | 
 2    |     B    | 2-jan-12  |  10:00   | 17:00   |   7   |        1     | 
 3    |     C    | 1-jan-12  |  10:00   | 12:00   |   2   |              | 
 3    |     C    | 1-jan-12  |  13:00   | 15:00   |   2   |              | 
 3    |     C    | 1-jan-12  |  20:00   | 23:00   |   3   |        1     |
```

My query is:

```
select 
      store, 
      employee,
      date,
      timein,
      timeout,
      cast(trim(trailing ':' from cast(timeout) as number)-trim(trailing ':' from cast(timein) as number) as number) as hours,
     case
      when timeout is null then 0 and
     end
from
      tableattend
where date between '1-jan-12' and '2-jan-12' and store between 'A' and 'C'
```

The **working_days** field is to be displayed in this way but could not get the exact function to create a result like the above. Please guide me.

Comment: You should think about changing the title of your question. Additionally, you should try to phrase the question in plain text.

Comment: What is the datatype of `timein` and `timeout` ? varchar2 ?

Comment: the third line complicates the problem.

Comment: Please explain what your requirements instead of posting some obscure code and asking us to guess what it's supposed to do.

Comment: the datatype of timein and timeout are varchar2 ..Here I need to get the working days field to show as 1 for each date

Comment: What do you mean by showing working days field to show as 1 for each date?

Comment: @APC see the history of edits. he need to generate the hours and days. I will edit the question now.

Comment: @AshReva Working_days need to generate the value 1 for distinct date in the last row of every date as in the format shown above. If there is null value in timeout in any date the working_days should generate as 0.

Comment: @Anish what is meaning of null, 0 and 1 values in working_days column?

Comment: @shibormot null is because the date has another row of values.* 0 is because the timeout value is null and on that date there is only one row so the value is displayed there.* 1 is because the row is the last of the same-date-rows and timeout is not null so the value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You state in the commments your rules for generating WORKING_DAYS are:

- if the record is not the last record for DATE then **NULL**
- if the record is the last record for DATE but TIMEOUT is null then **0**
- else **1**

This is a simplified version of your query which addresses the specific issue:

```
select date
       , timein 
       , timeout
       , case 
            when rn != 1 then null
            when timeout is null then 0
            else 1
          end as working_days
from ( select date
              , timein 
              , timeout
              , row_number() over partition by date order by timein desc ) rn
       from  tableattend
      where date between '1-jan-12' and '2-jan-12' 
      and store between 'A' and 'C' )
order by date, timein
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on APC's answer because I interpreted the working days rule slightly differently... this gives your expected output. but doesn't seem to match the rules you stated:

```
select store, employee, dt, timein, timeout, hours,
    case when rn = 1 then decode(tmp_timeout, null, 0, 1) end as working_days
from (
    select store, employee, dt, timein, timeout,
          case when timeout is null then 0
          else extract (hour from to_dsinterval('0 ' || timeout || ':00')
              - to_dsinterval('0 ' || timein || ':00'))
          end as hours,
          first_value(timeout)
              over (partition by store, employee, dt
                  order by timeout nulls first) as tmp_timeout,
          row_number()
              over (partition by store, employee, dt
                  order by timein desc) as rn
    from tableattend
)
where dt between '1-jan-12' and '2-jan-12'
-- and store between 'A' and 'C' -- store is numeric??
/
```

I called the date column `dt` to avoid the reserved word, but otherwise tried to match what you supplied.

```
     STORE EMPLOYEE DT        TIMEIN TIMEOUT      HOURS WORKING_DAYS
---------- -------- --------- ------ ------- ---------- ------------
         1 A        01-JAN-12 10:00  17:00            7              
         1 A        01-JAN-12 20:00  22:00            2            1 
         2 B        01-JAN-12 10:00                   0              
         2 B        01-JAN-12 17:00  20:00            3            0 
         2 B        02-JAN-12 10:00  17:00            7            1 
         3 C        01-JAN-12 10:00  12:00            2              
         3 C        01-JAN-12 13:00  15:00            2              
         3 C        01-JAN-12 20:00  23:00            3            1
```

This would be easier if you were storing time in and out as full dates rather than as separate (varchar2) columns. It isn't clear what would or should happen if someone worked past midnight, so the `timeout` would appear to be before the `timein`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of examples on how to subtract time portion to get hours only as in above examples. Not clear how do you get working days. I think you can divide working hours by 8 to get work days... All examples are tested:

```
SELECT round((time_diff/3600)/24, 1) days
     , trunc(time_diff/3600) hrs
     , trunc(mod(time_diff, 3600) / 60) mnt
     , trunc(mod(time_diff, 3600) / 60 /60) sec
  FROM
  (
   SELECT time_in, time_out, (time_out-time_in)* 86400 time_diff
     FROM 
   (
    SELECT to_date('01-JAN-2012 17:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') time_out
         , to_date('01-JAN-2012 10:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') time_in
      FROM dual
   ))
   /
```

Using Extract example:

```
 Select time_in, time_out, time_diff,
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_diff) days,
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_diff) hours,
        EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_diff) minutes,
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_diff) seconds
   From
   (
    Select time_in, time_out, (time_out - time_in) time_diff
      From
     (
      Select CAST(to_date('01-JAN-2012 17:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP) time_out
           , CAST(to_date('01-JAN-2012 10:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP) time_in
         From dual
    ))
  /
```